# PHP math divide it weird

Tags: php

I have

```
$a = $rowcount + $rowcount2 ; // this is 25
$b = 1000000000;
$total = $a / $b;
```

this gives me `$total = 2.5E-8;` but I want `0.000000025.` What is causing this?

Comment: Weird, mine gives me `2.4E-8`. Don't know why yours is rounding up like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell PHP how to format your number

```
printf('%.9f', $a / $b);
```

or to store in a variable...

```
$num = sprintf('%.9f', $a / $b);
```

Comment: how will you put it in variable?

Comment: @Grasper I've added an example

Comment: hm, for some reason, it didn't work the first time. Anyway, now it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Grasper `printf` vs `sprintf`. The former outputs, the latter returns

Comment: hm, why there is so many command tags, why can't we just simply use echo or return...??

Comment: @Grasper I have no idea what you mean. *Command tags*?

Comment: I meant built in functions like sprintf(), what do u call it?